# Magento 2 First Name is a required field Error While Placing Order

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, php-7, shipping-address

When I try to place an order after the `customer registration/Login`. `Magento 2.2.5` shows "`First Name is a required Field Error`".
A Sample error message is attached.
[image]

This is the response I am getting:
[image]

Comment: have un entering first name during checkout at Shipping address step?

Comment: Yes I am entering the first name..

Comment: @AmitBera any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: With Guest Users it works fine, but with logged in users it is showing this error..

Comment: Have u check any third party extension are used your system

Comment: No there are not any third party extensions that I am using.. I have recently migrated the data from magento 1.9 to magento 2.2.5. But I haven't faced any issue other then this..

Comment: Any help from your side will be highly appreciated..

Comment: I have just added the response of the request to the question.. May be that helps?

Comment: @AmitBera any clue?

Comment: @AmitBera this only happens when a registered customer choose a recent billing address rather then a different billing address.

Comment: Hi @UsmanYousaf, I'm also getting same error. How did you fix it? Please reply.