# Magento 2.2.5 - what are the mysql tables where shipping and billing address is stored?

Tags: database, php-7, magento-2.2.5

I want to know the name of the tables where the `Shipping and Billing addresses` are stored in `Magento 2.2.5` for the registered customers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`customer_address_entity` is the table where customer address is stored for registered customers. however if if customer is not logged in and for guest checkout address is stored in `quote_address` table.

Comment: can you please check this? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/242554/magento-2-first-name-is-a-required-field-error-while-placing-order

Answer (score 6):

There are tables where stored these address

```
 customer_address_entity

 quote_address

 sales_order_address
```

Comment: Do you have any idea like where are the rules like is_required for a specific field i.e. first name for the shipping and billing address are stored?

Comment: these all fields are attributes and if you go in table eav_attribute you can see here is_required column for these attributes

Comment: Actually, I am facing a problem.. The problem is when a registered customer proceed to place an order and click the place order button on the store he gets an error showing. "Please check the shipping address, First name is a required field". But for the guest customer it works fine without any issue..
Please check this:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/242554/magento-2-first-name-is-a-required-field-error-while-placing-order

Comment: can you check in admin to open your customer and check billing and shipping address that means first name is blank there

Comment: I have checked the admin as well. And the firstname is already there in firstname field in the address section of customer..

Comment: Any idea what could be the reason?. Still unable to resolve this issue.